# parsing with bison

Tags: c, yacc, bison

I bought Flex & Bison from O'Reilly but I'm having some trouble implementing a parser (breaking things down into tokens was no big deal).

Suppose I have a huge binary string and what I need to do is add the bits together - every bit is a token:

```
 [0-1] { return NUMBER;}
```

1101010111111

Or for that matter a collection of tokens with no "operation".

Would a such a grammar be correct?

```
calclist :
         | calclist expr EOL {eval($2)}
expr: NUMBER
      |expr NUMBER { $$=$1+$2 }
```

or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Note that you probably want '`$$ = $1 * 2 + $2;` to accumulate bits into a binary number.

Comment: +1 for writing left-recursive rules

Answer (score 2):

Your example lex rule "[0-1] { return NUMBER; }" doesn't set yylval, so if you use that value in your grammar (as you do in the rule "expr NUMBER { $$=$1+$2; }") you'll get garbage.

In general what you're doing is correct, though the task you've chosen is so trivial that lex/bison is serious overkill.

Comment: this is not the task, it was just easier for me to put it this way :)

Comment: @codenewbie - He is right, though. Pay a bit closer attention to his first paragraph.